# How to execute jar file with a external dependency using command line on Windows?

Tags: java, maven, jar, cmd

I have jar file with manifest in it

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_67
    Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.3
    Main-Class: com.company.main.Main
    Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

And the jar has compile dependency to external library

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
```

So I want to execute it comandLine I wrote:

```
java -cp C:\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar -jar myJar-1.0.0.jar
```

But

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
        at ...
```

How to add this file on the class path?

PS. If I use the "bad way" and copy-paste **commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar** in the **...jre7\lib\ext** folder. Everything is working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're not using the -jar option then you need to specify the main class to run, as the manifest will not be interrogated:

```
java -cp C:\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;.\myJar-1.0.0.jar com.company.main.Main
```

The classpath (-cp) option is ignored if using the -jar option (in that case the manifest should reference any other required jars via its classpath directive).

Comment: kudos for explaining alternative to -jar. Went over 5-6 similar questions to get that detail.

Answer (score 1):

"Bad Way"..? You should never include your jar files inside the java directories.. How do you expect the users of your application to use your jar when they are using the standard java..?

either you can use the command suggested by @tombola82 or you can include the commons-lang jar in your project itself so that you can refer it.